# Front end URL to restore a post/page

Tags: revisions

I was wondering if a url exists where one can click on a link and would automatically populate in the edit post of the most current revision.

revision.php?action=restore&revision={newestcurrentrevisionID} doesn't seem to work. all it does is brings me to the revisions page.

Am I supposed to link to post.php? what would the action be?